# S3 to DynamoDB via Hive data export

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, amazon-dynamodb, emr, amazon-emr

I have comma-separated .csv without columns with rows like:

```
,310795849829453824,AAAAAQ==,Z3JvdXAtY2hhdA==,,
,310795709316075520,AAAAAA==,,,
,310778976203182080,AAAAAQ==,Z3JvdXAtY2hhdA==,,
,310795895400566784,AAAAAA==,,,
,310791016598736896,AAAAAQ==,Z3JvdXAtY2hhdA==,,
```

It's stored in S3, and I define external table as following:

```
create external table s3_chats(AVATAR BINARY, CHAT_ID BIGINT, CHAT_TYPE BINARY, NAME BINARY, VENUE_ID BINARY, VENUE_NAME BINARY) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' location 's3://dynamocsv/export/chats/'
```

Everything is ok at this step, but when I try to

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dynamo_chats SELECT * FROM s3_chats
```

DynamoDB error is raised:

```
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"avatar":,"chat_id":310795849829453824,"chat_type":^@^@^@^A,"name":group-chat,"venue_id":,"venue_name":}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"avatar":,"chat_id":310795849829453824,"chat_type":^@^@^@^A,"name":group-chat,"venue_id":,"venue_name":}
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:550)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:177)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain a null or empty binary type. (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 1UQEO408OB918GASELHM5V2NB3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
        at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.handleException(DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.runWithRetry(DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.java:83)
        at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBClient.writeBatch(DynamoDBClient.java:217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBClient.putBatch(DynamoDBClient.java:167)
        at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.AbstractDynamoDBRecordWriter.write(AbstractDynamoDBRecordWriter.java:92)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.write.HiveDynamoDBRecordWriter.write(HiveDynamoDBRecordWriter.java:29)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:649)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:793)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:87)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:793)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:92)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:793)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:540)
        ... 9 more
```

That's actually makes sense: you shouldn't specify row you don't want to write in request.

Is it `DynamoDBStorageHandler` bug or maybe there is some workaround for writing optional fields via Hive?

Comment: Which of "AVATAR BINARY, CHAT_ID BIGINT, CHAT_TYPE BINARY, NAME BINARY, VENUE_ID BINARY, VENUE_NAME BINARY" is your primary key? Primary key values cannot be optional.

Comment: CHAT_ID is hash ("primary key") in DynamoDB.